# Azure backup container registered using New-AzureRMBackupVault fails to load in the portal

Tags: azure

Since I am unable to specify the resource group for a new Backup Vault when creating it in the Azure Portal, I created the vault using the New-AzureRMBackupVault powershell commandlet.  This appears to work through powershell, and an item shows up in the preview portal under my resource group.  However, clicking on the vault in the portal (which redirects to the old portal) results in errors when trying to show any details for it.

> > Couldn't load dashboard details. Please try after sometime. Contact Microsoft support if issue persists. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support.
> >
> > Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your full code? I use the code below to create a backup vault,

```
New-AzureResourceGroup -name "test-stackover" -Location "West US"
New-AzureRmBackupVault -ResourceGroupName "test-stackover" -name "test-vault" -Region "West US"
Get-AzureRmBackupVault
```

When I click the test-vault on the preview portal, it redirects to the old portal without the above error. Please could you provide more details, so I can monitor to catch the error.
Try again after you finish the step:`Download, install, and register the Azure Backup agent.`
Please see more information from the articles: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-client-automation/, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-dpm-introduction/

Comment: Actual call is:
>>$vault = New-AzureRmBackupVault -ResourceGroupName "ICSP-DEV" -name "test-vault" -Region "West US"
When you get into the portal, if you click on "Registered Items" are you able to do anything?  I have not buttons on the bottom to "discover" etc.  Just get the error toast message.  I am planning on backing up cloud VM's so I shouldn't need to install the Azure backup agent etc.

Comment: I can see `Registered Items` and `DISCOVERY`, I can see  `You haven’t registered any items yet. To get started, register the items you want to protect and then protect them using Protect action.` on `Registered Items` page, it prompt to backup Windows server or backup Azure Virtual Machine...any problem?

Comment: you mean you want  to backup VM?

Comment: Thanks @Lily_user4045  When I go to **Registered Items** I always get an error **"Please try again.  If the problem persists, contact support"**.  It looks like it works correctly for you though.  
Yes, I am trying to backup VM's.

Comment: The error is strange, is your account an Administrator or Co-Administrator?